# "ValueError: Merge keys contain null values on right side" using pd.merge_asof

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to merge two dataframes using pd.merge_asof. There is a 'Date2' in df2 related to 'Date1' in df1. However, there are some rows where there is no 'Date2'.

I tried the below code to merge both dataframes, but I'm getting the following error: ValueError: Merge keys contain null values on right side

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('Date1', ascending=True), 
                              df2.sort_values("Date2",ascending=True),
                               left_on='Date1', 
                               right_on='Date2', 
                               by=['Country','City','Location'], 
                               direction='forward')
```

Could anyone please help me to figure out how to handle the null values on Date2.

Comment: Add a `.dropna(subset=['Date2'])` on the end of the right DataFrame you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to remove the rows that have NaN values. Or use [.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill those rows with a default value `.fillna(0)` or use `.fillna(method='ffill')` to fill with the values from previous rows.